# Getting error 403 when adding YouTube embed code in Wordpress Elementor

Tags: wordpress, youtube, embed, elementor

I get 403 error when I update the YouTube `embed` code

in Wordpress with Elementor.

[image]

May I be adding to wrong component ?

 I had been inserted into Special HTML;

[image]

How can I fix this ?
Thanks.

Comment: I may have been installed the Elemontor plugins in wrong way. I will remove and install again

Comment: And I may have been used the Elementor in wrong way

Comment: you can use video element from elementor page module and just add video URL only

Comment: @wpdevloper_j Thanks, I have asked it's question, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67926940/video-is-not-seen-in-wordpress-when-using-tags