# Video is not seen in blank Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, video, youtube, ftp

I have deleted everything on FTP

and reinstalled everything including DB

for a virus.

Now has a totally blank WordPress,

only has Astra theme.

But I cannot see the video or video link in any way.

[image]

my page:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm new to Wordpress. I may have been missed something.

Comment: There is a topic in official forum, as I understand, there is a problem with the <object> tag, in Wordpress videos https://ios.forums.wordpress.org/topic/embed-a-video-works-as-admin-fails-as-author-embedded-code-disappears?replies=7

Comment: I found so many Wordpress video plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For main page, I had to set not a video, but a featured image on below of the Wordpress post page.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong. I was trying to make the links and video appear on the main page, it turns out that the descriptions there are mini-discriptions and the link and video are not visible there. They only appear on the side pages. Pardon. I thought they would appear on the homepage like custom design.

Answer (score 0):

Use a plugin to add videos in the wordpress website. So your problem will be solved.

Comment: The problem is; I couldn't add a video on the main page. But no problem, currently I can add image rather than video.